# Python Training: How to access, add, then remove values from a Dictionary, using a list indicating the positions that need to be removed

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

GO FISH game:

The Problem: How to access, add, then remove values from a Dictionary, using a list indicating the positions that need to be removed.  Is there a more elegant way to search dicts for partial strings instead of reducing to lists for searching?

Code Flow Chart:

- Player 1 ask Player 2 whether they have a particular card,
  dest_card=’4’.
- Determine where 4's exist in dest_player values from dictionary,
  hand[1]
- Record positions of partial values.
- Since only partial Search, need to determine full value of items
  matching so add/remove can be used on dictionary.
- Add values(positions) to Player 1, hands[0]
- Remove values(positions) from Player 2, hands[1]

Setup:

2 Players.

Their hands of cards are stored in a Dictionary of cards, where key=(player# - 1), and values are their current Cards.

```
hands={
'0': ['4C', '8S', 'JD', '8H', 'JC', '5D', '8D'],
'1': ['4H', '4D', '3C', '6H', 'QS', '7C', '9S']
}
```

In this example, Player 1 asks Player 2 for 4’s.  We can see visually that 4’s exist in the 0th, and 1th positions.  Now need code to determine this, so action can be taken.

In code:

I need to find all instances where where dest_card exists in Player 2’s hand, and then add those values to Player 1 hand, and remove those values from Player 2 hand.

Using the magic of enumerate, I can run the following function to test the list of Player 2’s hands for matching strings. Dest_card is a string. Hands in this function is the dictionary reduced to a list by inputing hands[str(int(dest_player)-1)]) as hands in my call.

The return is an index list of values matching dest_card (4’s in this example)

The problem is I am working with a list, not a dict.  I have to translate the ordinal positions of matching values to commands that will work at a dictionary level.

```
findindexofmatchingcards(dest_card, hands[str(int(dest_player)-1)]))


def findindexofmatchingcards(dest_card,hands):
    """Return a List of Indices where Dest_Card is matched.  Does not return values"""

    print("Starting Indices Function Matching")
    indices = []
    for i, elem in enumerate(hands):
        if dest_card in elem:
            indices.append(i)
    print("Indices are:",indices)
    return(indices)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can combine this logic into a single function rather than doing it in multiple stages:

```
hands = {
    '0': ['4C', '8S', 'JD', '8H', 'JC', '5D', '8D'],
    '1': ['4H', '4D', '3C', '6H', 'QS', '7C', '9S']
}


def update_hands(requesting_player_id, target_player_id, request):

    requesting_player_id -= 1  # Adjust for player id vs hand index
    target_player_id -= 1      # Adjust for player id vs hand index

    matching_cards = [c for c in hands[str(target_player_id)] if c[0] == request]

    # Update hands
    hands[str(requesting_player_id)] += matching_cards
    hands[str(target_player_id)] = [c for c in hands[str(target_player_id)] if c not in matching_cards]


print(hands)
update_hands(1, 2, '4')  # Player 1 asks Player 2 for '4's
print(hands)
```

Gives:

```
{'0': ['4C', '8S', 'JD', '8H', 'JC', '5D', '8D'],
 '1': ['4H', '4D', '3C', '6H', 'QS', '7C', '9S']}

{'0': ['4C', '8S', 'JD', '8H', 'JC', '5D', '8D', '4H', '4D'],
 '1': ['3C', '6H', 'QS', '7C', '9S']}
```

Edit:

An explanation of the `matching_cards` line:

```
matching_cards = [                   # start a list comprehension
    c for c                          # card for card
    in hands[str(target_player_id)]  # in the target hand
    if c[0] == request               # if the first part of the card == what's been requested
]
```

Comment: Let me study this.  It appears that enumeration function didn't aid me, and you're accomplishing this directly.  

The matching_cards statement [ ] is unfamiliar to me, particularly as a single line statement.  Let me see if I can disassemble it into multiple statements to understand better what is being accomplished here.  Thank you for the swift reply

Comment: @PhilC if you want to learn more about this kind of statement, it is called list comprehension.

Comment: @PhilC - I've added an explanation of the line you mention.

Comment: Having issues with double-digit requests.

Hands ={'0': ['8D', '4D', '2H', '5H', 'AS', 'AC', '9D'], '1': ['10S', '6C', '2D', 'KS', '3S', '10C', '7C'], '2': ['8C', 'KC', 'QS', '6S', '5D', '9D', '8S'], '3': ['6C', 'JS', '4S', '5D', '9H', '8H', 'AH'], '4': ['2C', 'AS', '4D', 'KC', 'AH', '6S', '10H']}

As player 1, I ask player 2 for "10".

My indices functions returns: Indices are: [0, 5] where 10s exist.

However list comprehension returns: []

Comment: My Dictionary values are a concatenation of [Card#][Suit].  When I ask 10, this is the only case where the card string becomes 3 digits.  For example, 10S, 10 Spades.

Could the c[0] be adjusted somehow to pull starting with?

Comment: yep - slice off the last character instead: `matching_cards = [c for c in hands[str(target_player_id)] if c[:-1] == request]`. This will work for all cards, as `c[:-1]` returns `'10'` for `'10D'` and `'5'` for `'5D'`